# Discrete Math Probability - Consider a $3\times 3$ grid composed of $9$ unit squares.

Tags: probability

Consider a $3\times3$ grid composed of $9$ unit squares. Each of the unit squares is randomly colored black or white. What is the probability that at least one $2 \times 2$ square in this grid will be completely black?

I'm not really sure how to do this problem at all. My guess would be to find the total outcome $|\Omega|$ and the event set and find $\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$. But I'm not sure how to find either of these!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Finding $|\Omega|$ is not too difficult... Finding $|A|$ takes somewhat more thought.

Comment: The central square must be black.  Two, three or four of the adjacent squares must be black.  Go through each of the options.

Comment: There are four $2 \times 2$ squares in a $3 \times 3$ grid.  You can use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to count $|A|$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $LU,LD,RU,RD$ denote the events that the left upper, left down, right upper an right down  $2\times 2$ square will be completely black respectively.

Then we are looking for $$P(LU\cup LD\cup RU\cup RD)$$

With [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and symmetry we find that this equals:$$4P(LU)-4P(LU\cap LD)-2P(LU\cap RD)+4P(LU\cap LD\cap RU)-P(LU\cap LD\cap RU\cap RD)=$$$$4\cdot2^{-4}-4\cdot2^{-6}-2\cdot2^{-7}+4\cdot2^{-8}-2^{-9}$$